# How to make this perfect shape in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I want to learn how to create this shape in illustrator. What are the ways to create this with perfect geometry?

I tried to create a part of the shape and used rotate duplicate method but I can't achieve the desired results. I want to just learn how to create such graphics, not for commercial use, just for learning purposes.

[image]

Comment: OK. This seems to be appeared in the question, too. Remember: non-commercial usage also needs a license. A copy is a copy, no matter do you sell it or do you give it or show it for free.

Comment: I rolled this back. The image goes **a long way** to explaining what you are trying to do and I feel is imperative to the question. The additional text explaining the purpose makes it clear that you are just seeking knowledge `:)` This, I think, qualifies as "editorial usage" and "fair use". Nothing is being gained by the use of the image other than explanation. I don't think using it in this manner is an issue and it HAS the watermark. So, if anything it's an advertisement for Shutterstock.

Answer (score 1):

The key is working with symbols. This will allow you to edit the shape later to reach the desired form.

start with a basic shape

[image]

Convert the shape to symbols  and do the copy-paste-rotate trick several times to get the circle.

[image]

Finaly edit the symbol to get the shape ajusted to your desire. Break the link to symbols to add different colors.

[image]

Comment: The drawing actually uses spirals

Answer (score 1):

I will not show you how to recreate the graphic, since it is clearly copyright, and I would advise against copying it. However I will add an answer for personal practice/educational purposes only.

Anyway, using the rotate and copy method which you already mentioned is exactly how such a design would be created.

What you might not be aware of is that these are in fact segments of spirals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I've two things to add to this discussion:

### First, a method for generating radial arrays of shapes to make "such perfect shapes".

The big initial circle is for reference only; the guides crossing at it centre are fro snapping. I grouped my initial single squiggle and its two associated dots, selected the **R**otate **T**ool, and with it selected, left-clicked once at the intersection of the guidelines I'd drawn at the circle's centre. This shifts the rotate tool's centre-of-action. I then rotated a duplicate of the initial squiggle-and-dots.

[image]

Rinse and repeat till satisfied.

[image]

Delete centre reference circle, select opposing pairs of elements, and recolour as needed for best effect.

[image]

### And secondly, the shutterstock licensing info:

[image: Shutterstock Licensing]

So if you want to use their design content, this is what it will cost you to do so. As @user287001 so correctly commented, even if you redraw that other designer's work yourself, that woulds still be a literal copying of their copyrighted designwork - and either you pay up-front for the license, or you pay ***way*** more later when you get sued and they handily win, getting both back licensing fees and liquidated damages - really not a worthit approach at all, morally, legally or financially.

Hope this helps.